# Raven DB Replication Setup Issue

Tags: installation, replication, ravendb

Can any one help me in setting up Raven DB Replication? Tried a lot of
ways a lot of time but no success.

Here is the story:

1) I downloaded the raven bundle. Make a copy of it. Run
Raven.Server.Exe from both of the folders. Both instances run
successfully on individual port. Then I created a document with name
as "Raven/Replication/Destinations"  and document as

{
 "Destinations": [{"Url":"http://vishal-pc:8081"}],
 "Id": "Raven/Replication/Destinations"
}

But it's not working. Please some one put some light no How can I
setup replication.

One more thing I want to mention here is, I was able to run the
replication by running "start raven.ps1" from samples/
Raven.Sample.Replication from bundle.Both instances are already has
the Raven/Replication/Destinations" document like below (no url in
destination node):
{
 "Destinations": [],
 "Id": "Raven/Replication/Destinations"
}

Then I updated one instance with url of another instance. After
updating document was like below:
{
 "Destinations": ["Url":"http://vishal-pc:8081"],
 "Id": "Raven/Replication/Destinations"
}

and replication works fantastically.

I am not able to figure out what is the difference here. Why It's not
able to replication When I run two instances separately and why it is
working fine by running "start raven.ps1".

Please please please some one put some light here.

Note : I am using web interface to make changes in document.

Thanks
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

Look in the folder of the Raven.Server.exe file you are executing. Make sure you have a subdirectory called `Plugins` and that it contains the replication bundle DLL.

[This blog post](http://freshbrewedcode.com/davidneal/2012/06/12/how-to-configure-ravendb-database-replication/) walks you through that process pretty well.