# RavenDB Replication Issue

Tags: ravendb

I have a requirement, I have two DB hosted @ different port's!

For now, let it be at different port as 8080 and 8081

Now, when ever there is any change in RavenDB @ port 8080, it should get reflected into 8081 port DB.

Currently,
I am able to dig into the Raven Sample Application folder

> Raven\Samples\Raven.Sample.Replication
>   
>   And execute(After going thru some blog post's and previous question from StackOverflow
>   [Raven DB Replication Setup Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540186/raven-db-replication-setup-issue))
>
> Start Raven.ps1

```
var documentStore1 = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080" }.Initialize();
        var documentStore2 = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8081" }.Initialize();
```

After Initializing DocumentStore, i am trying to save Data

```
using(var session1 = documentStore1.OpenSession())
        {
            session1.Store(new User { Id = "users/ayende", Name = "Ayende" });
            session1.SaveChanges();
        }




        using (var session2 = documentStore2.OpenSession())
        {
            session2.Store(new User { Id = "users/ayende", Name = "Oren" });
            session2.SaveChanges();
        }
```

As per my understanding, it should get reflected in Both the DB's. Please rectify, if i am wrong?
But this is not happening!

If, i execute the first set of insert query :-

```
using(var session1 = documentStore1.OpenSession())
        {
            session1.Store(new User { Id = "users/ayende", Name = "Ayende" });
            session1.SaveChanges();
        }
```

It only save's in port 8080 but not in 8081.

Please let me know, how can i achieve the desired(Replication).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't setup the replication bundle. That is what causes the replication.
You can do that via the instructions in: http://old.ravendb.net/documentation/replication